# How can i wrap a word from a p in an a tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `p tag` and I want to wrap a word in an `a tag`

Lorem ipsum @dolor sit amet, consectetur  **to** 
Lorem ipsum [@dolor](http://#!) sit amet, consectetur

I've tried this:

```
objectP = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
$.each(objectP, function(i, val){

    arrayWords = val.innerHTML.split(" ")

    $.each(arrayWords, function(i, val){

        if(val[0] === '@'){

            val.wrap("<a></a>")

        }

    })

})
```

Comment: You want to wrap all the words that starts with `@` in `<a>` tag? What should be `href` value for the replaced anchor element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex  with capturing group to make things simpler

```
objectP = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

$.each(objectP, function(i, val){
    val.innerHTML = val.innerHTML.replace(/(@.*?)\s/g, "<a href='#'>$1</a>");
})
```

Here `(@.*?)` is the capturing group and `$1` will have the captured string from the entire matched string.

Comment: This solution wont work for strings like `@dolor's` or `@dolor-3`

Answer (score 0):

Since You are using jQuery anyways try this

```
$("p").each(function(){
  $(this).replaceWith($(this).html().replace(/(@[^\s]+)/,"<a href='#'>$1</a>"))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Good 'ol fashioned looping:

```
  var paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');

  [].map.call(paragraphs, function(p) {
    var htmlArray = p.innerHTML.split(' ');

    htmlArray.map(function(word, i, arr) {
      if(word === '@dolor') {
        var a = '<a href="#">' + word + '</a>';
        arr[i] = a;
      }
    });

    p.innerHTML = htmlArray.join(' ');
  });
```